# MariaDB + Phpmyadmin Migration went wrong. "Not enough privilege to view users."

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Old system: Ubuntu 20.04; 
New system: Debian 11

What I have done so far:

1. Dumped MariaDB from the old system with

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | gzip > fullbackup.sql.gzip
```

2. Imported to the new system with

```
gunzip < fullbackup.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p
```

3. I installed PHPMyAdmin with apt-get install PHPMyAdmin

What are the current problems:

1. Not all my databases are imported. I can see missing databases after the import.
2. I have zero ideas how to see all the users in MARIADB
3. Phpmyadmin is saying, "Not enough privilege to view users".
4. I tried `mysql> select * from mysql.user; REPAIR TABLE user` nothing works

What I think got messed up:

1. The old system version of mariadb is 10.3.32 the new one is 10.5.12
2. Somehow the users table got messed up forever `ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 56937: Table 'user' already exists`
3. There may be a misconfiguration in the Phpmyadmin I don't know how to fix.

Help me get my new server up and running, please! I am not an advanced user.

Comment: I am nearly sure that they are a diff is in the table of the mysql System Schema. so you CANT save a old version and restore in a newer MySQL/MariaDB version .
if you do that you lose the new fields of this version and the DB can crash

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 10.4 mysql.users is not a table anymore, but a view into mysql.global_priv table.

It looks like you missed to run `mariadb_upgrade`. I didn't test if mariadb_upgrade in 10.5 also handles upgrade from 10.3, the usual way is to upgrade each version (10.3 - > 10.4 -> 10.5).